# How do I set up a field recorder with camera/wireless monitoring?

Tags: field-recording

This has to do with production sound. If you're a mixer, please help me, because I cannot wrap my head around this. I am a total newbie.

Here's the scenario.

Not working explicitly with this device, but since it makes for a head scratching example, take the Zaxcom Maxx (http://www.trewaudio.com/store/Zaxcom-Maxx-Mixer-Recorder.html)

This nifty little recorder has several outputs.

- 1x TA5 Mono(?) tape out
- 1x TA5 "Aux 1/2" out, a sum of Out 1 & 2
- 1x TA5 Stereo(?) Return
- 2x XLR Outputs

I am assuming from Zaxcom's manual that they are all balanced connections.

NOW. I want to send my stereo mix from the Zaxcom Maxx to a camera, which has two Mic/Line selectable XLR inputs, AND to a Comtek M-216 transmitter.

I have no idea how to do this. Obviously for camera you would use the two XLR outs with some kind of twin/braided XLR cable, right? Does that cable even exist?

Do you use the tape out for the Comtek? TA5 to stereo mini?

Very confused. Please help.

Comment: I agree with AJ's comment below: "Any reason not to timecode sync them and combine in post if running two cables is really a problem."  There is also software available that can sync audio tracks without timecode, so is it the cables that's the problem?  Also, I'm unclear as to why you're specifically interested in responses from mixers.  I'm not really an audio guy, but if your problem is integrating audio with video, then I might be able to help.  Please clarify your question or provide us with additional info so we can help you clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest bet, use a distribution amplifier.  If you need the same audio to both, a DA will boost the signal so that it can actually go to both.  Not sure what the inputs on the Comtek are though, the DA will generally work best if they can both take XLR in.  Also, are you mixing in stereo?  If not, do you need two XLR to the camera?

As for the cable to the camera, you could heat shrink wrap two XLRs if you can't find a basic 2 channel XLR snake (assuming you are looking to have only one "cable" going to the camera.  Any reason not to timecode sync them and combine in post if running two cables is really a problem.